# How can I disable `Initializing JS/TS Language Features` in a specific project?

Tags: laravel, visual-studio-code

I have a Laravel project developing it inside the Visual Studio Code.
Also I have the front-end with Angular 8 in a separate project which also use VSC.
I build the Angular project and push the build version inside the Laravel project.

Now when I am working on my Laravel project `VSC` shows `Initializing JS/TS Language Features` message all the time inside the footer and it heavily impacts the performance of my computer.

[image: error picture in vsc]

As I am using this feature in other projects, is there a way to disable this feature just in a specific project? In this case in my Laravel project.

Comment: Just a "shot in the dark", but how recently have you updated your VS Code?

Comment: It is latest version all the times.

Comment: I disabled the extension. It's such badly behaving that only causes a headache.

Comment: In my case, this message persisted and eventually the extension manager crashed, resulting in none extension working properly. The problem was the 3rd party TS script in my project was transpilling the source code to a separate folder which reached 10GB+ in size, leading the JS/TS extension to crash. I removed that folder and everything worked as expected.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Disabling TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features built-in extension for a specific workspace helped to me (in my case the extension had been slowing down the performance of the machine and messing with autocomplete in React apps).

In your VSCode window:

> Show All Commands (`Ctrl/Cmd` + `Shift` + `P`) -> Type "Extensions: Show Built-in Extensions" -> Features -> TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features -> Disable (Workspace)

And reload your VSCode after that.

Comment: What does the `Workplace` means here? Does it mean the project folder? I don't want to disable it for all projects. I want to disable it only for a specific project.

Comment: This extension is a disaster. It eats all cpu time from all cpu cores. Really badly behaving and buggy.

Comment: Oh. Those exist.

Comment: This "solution" unfortunately disables all [JavaScript features](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/javascript) such as navigation, hover information, auto imports, formatting, references codelens, static analysis, etc.

Comment: I could not find the "TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features" extension with the procedure described above. See @Ahmad Awais solution below (type "@builtin"  in the extension search box)

Answer (score 40):

`TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` is a default built-in extension of VSCode. To disable it, do the following

- Go to extensions view

  *macOS:* <kbd>COMMAND (⌘)</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT (⇧)</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>

  *Windows/Linux:* <kbd>CONTROL (⌃)</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT (⇧)</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd>
- Write `@builtin` in the search box and then search for the extension you'd want to disable, e.g. in your case `TypeScript and JavaScript Language Features` — now you can disable it.
- I recommend only disabling it for your current `Workspace` i.e. current project

Here's a handy gif:

[image: built in extension disable vscode]

Comment: This worked for me. I think it should be the recommended answer.

Comment: this thing is crashing my VM every time, the most useless and buggy feature ever

Comment: This is a solution that works for most. 

Answer (score 15):

Disabling Language Features for TS and JS will work, but you'll also lose other features (pre-compile type checking, validating, etc.).  The specific problem is due to the delay in executing Code Actions and isn't directly related to TS.

Yes, disabling Language Features will solve the problem, but you can target the root cause and keep the language features active!

In the user settings you want to disable "editor.codeActionsOnSave" for any particular features that are slowing you down. In my case, it was ESLint automatically fixing code actions on save; from my settings.json:

```
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": false
},
```

Disabling this let me keep language features enabled, but removed the conflict (Prettier was formatting my code on save, ESLint was fixing issues on save, and together there was a slowdown).

Comment: Nice, this was driving me crazy. Just out of curiosity, how did you make the connection that this was the cause?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by bumping op the "Max TS Server Memory". This reduced loading time exponentialy. I've set mine to 7072.
(Ctrl + ,) and search "memory".

[Settings in vs code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JoYox.png)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34572541)

Answer (score -1):

Open VS code command palette (Ctrl-Shift-P) and choose 'Angular: Restart Angular Language server'

Not a permanent solution, but it can help.