# VSCode `Saving Getting code actions from`

Tags: visual-studio-code

Getting frequent `Saving Getting code actions from` from VSCode.

VSCode freezes, the file is NOT saved. It seems to happen for Prettier, Eslint, React plugins, so many. This didn't used to happen, know it happens all the time.

Is there a way to STOP this from happening?

Comment: Same happening to me. Did you find the cause?

Comment: this is the solution you can try this out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60026235/10106066

Answer (score 11):

I had the following in my VSCode `settings.json`, which seemed to cause this problem while saving Python files:

```json
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
}
```

The fix for me was to enable this option only for TypeScript:

```
"[typescript]": {
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I had the same issue saving c# files. My .vscode folder was originally at the root of a TS project. This problem occurred when I decided to include a C# project in the same vscode workspace.

Answer (score 4):

Reload you vscode editor with the [reload plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1055#issuecomment-832470210)

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-eslint/issues/1055#issuecomment-832470210

Comment: Reloading works but is not a long-term solution if this happens every 2 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but after I configure my setting.json file like below, it did save alot faster!

```json
"editor.formatOnSave": true,
"eslint.format.enable": true,
"editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
  "source.fixAll.eslint": true
},
"editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
"[jsonc]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
},
"[typescript]": {
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": false
  }
}
```

Comment: You disabled running ESLint for typescript on save, that's probably why it became faster. It also helps showing that the problem is with ESLint formatting.

Answer (score 0):

delete extension code style without ESLint and Prettier.

Answer (score 0):

If it was caused by ESLint (you may see the "ESLint failed to start 5 times in the last 3 minutes" notification), it's likely caused by ESLint using too much memory and caused by the "JavaScript heap out of memory" error. Check your output to confirm.

If it is the case, you may want to check if you added node_modules or your build output folders to the ignore pattern in your eslintrc or eslintignore files. If you haven't try doing that. Mine was caused by ESLint going through everything in the node_modules folder and that caused the OOM error. Adding the ignore pattern solved the issue for me.